# Addressing event handlers in XML: `.myHandler` or `myHandler`?

Tags: sapui5

I've paid attention, in some UI5-samples, I can see `press=".onCloseDialog"`, in another: `press="onCloseDialog"`.

I mean, in some cases, the name of controller's method in XML-template is written with the leading dot and sometimes without. Is it a matter of a taste?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it a matter of a taste?

No. According to [*Addressing the Event Handler*](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/b0fb4de7364f4bcbb053a99aa645affe):

> - Names starting with a dot ('.') are always assumed to represent a **method in the controller**. [...] These names are relative to the view/controller. For example, `press=".myLocalHandler"` is resolved by `attachPress(oController["myLocalHandler"], oController);`.
> - Names without dot are interpreted as a relative name; if nothing is found, they are interpreted as an absolute name. **This variant is only supported for backward compatibility.**

<sup>--> See also the [message from the commit `226bc69`](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/226bc69e36229de74d6338d560af8cf9e9b49dd8).</sup>

Use always `press=".onCloseDialog"` when referring to the controller method.